# getId() returns '[Function]' in Google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, return-value

I'm trying to find a specific event in a calendar using the contents of an email but whilst trying to find the event using

```
var today = new Date();
var events = CalendarApp.getEventsForDay(today);
console.log(events[0].getId);
```

I get returned "[Function]" instead of the event Id.

This is the same no matter what I use if I change date, specifics in getEventsForDay, or if I change it to getTitle etc. All I get returned is 'Function' instead of the eventid or title etc.

Answer (score 0):

> `console.log(events[0].getId);`
> I get returned "[Function]" instead of the event Id.

That is the correct result, because `Event.getId()` indeed is a function. To *evaluate* the function and get the event ID, add parentheses `()` to the function name, like this:

```
console.log(events[0].getId());
```

Comment: Kicking myself that I missed that haha